# Access to the same class instance from qml

Tags: class, qml, qt5

I'm using Qt 5.1.0 and QtQuick 2.0.
I've just learned how to exchange data and method between qml and C++. In detail, I want to expose a (nested) structure, so I created classes which contains the required properties and methods.

It works, but I cannot share the very same instance between C++ and qml. Changing something from C++ side leads to no changes in qml side.

A short example:

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"
#include "myclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<MyClass>("MyLibrary", 1, 0, "MyClass");

    MyClass *myclass = new MyClass();
    Category *cat = new Category();
    cat->setName("foo");
    myclass->append(cat);
    qDebug() << myclass->categoriesCount(); // returns 1 OK!

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/main.qml"));
    viewer.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

myclass.h

```
#include <QObject>

class Category : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)

public:
    Category() {}
    QString name() const { return m_name; }
    void setName(QString name) { m_name = name; }

private:
    QString m_name;
};

class MyClass : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QList<QObject*> categories READ categories NOTIFY categoriesChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int categoriesCount READ categoriesCount)

public:
    QList<QObject*> categories() const { return m_categories; }
    void clear() { m_categories.clear(); }
    void append(Category *category) { m_categories.append(category); }
    int categoriesCount() const { return m_categories.count(); }

private:
    QList<QObject*> m_categories;

signals:
    void categoriesChanged();
};
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import MyLibrary 1.0

Item {
    id: root
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Text {
        id: foo
        text: myclass.categoriesCount // writes 0 -> should be 1
    }

    MyClass {
        id: myclass
    }    
}
```

I'm afraid the qml engine accesses to a different instance of the class myclass created in the main file.

Comment: I think I was completely wrong. I removed the qmlRegisterType and added a setContextProperty("myclass", MyClass). It seems to work now.

Comment: This makes sense since qmlRegisterType enables QML to create instances of the type while setContextProperty actually sets instances of objects as accessible in QML.  If your problem is solved add your answer as an answer and mark it as accepted so it shows up as answered!